# bootstrap fixed-width vs fluid-width in mobile and broswer

Tags: user-interface, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-website

In the bootstrap application, what layout best suit both mobile and browser user interface? fixed-width layout or fluid-width layout? Do I need explicitly define the css media query styles for both design?

Answer (score 0):

You may use *Bootstrap's* responsive deisgn by which your website will automatically adjust itself in order to give users a comfortable experience for whatever size device they’re using..

For it's application you need to include *meta viewport tag* under your `<head>..</head>` tags in addition to including Bootstrap’s responsive stylesheet

```
<head> 
.. 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
.. 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css" /> 
..
</head>
```

You may check [further details here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) and also [this article](http://blog.inspiringapps.com/layout-and-responsive-design-with-twitter-bootstrap/)

So, If you have correctly setup your page with containers, rows, and spans, *Bootstrap* will automatically adjust the layout for each device you are viewing the website on..